# how to make the Circular layer larger keeping the center fixed

Tags: ios, transform, cashapelayer, cabasicanimation

I have a circlular CAShapeLayered UIView centered at the parents view. Now when I tap on this view, I want to increase its overall radius by 50%. So, I have this following animation code attached to my layer.

```
private func getLargerLayerAnimation()->CABasicAnimation { 
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
    animation.fromValue = 1
    animation.toValue = 1.5
    animation.duration = 2.0
    animation.autoreverses = true
    animation.fillMode = .forwards
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = true
    return animation
}
```

but rather than enlarging the layer from its center, it is moving down-rightwards. How to keep the center intact and enlarge the circular layer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the bounds of your layer to match the size of the circle layer.

Here is some sample code :

```
    let circleBounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
    let circle = CAShapeLayer()
    circle.bounds = circleBounds      // <<<<<======
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: circleBounds)
    circle.path = circlePath.cgPath
    
    view.layer.addSublayer(circle)
    circle.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
    self.view = view
    
    circle.add(getLargerLayerAnimation(), forKey: "dummy")
```